# Don't want to use constructor in subclass

Tags: java, constructor, super

In my program I have 4 classes like the following:

- `class Bank`
- `class Branch extends Bank`
- `class Customer extends Branch`
- `class Loan extends Customer`

If I want to add a `Customer`, then I give all the parameters from main function. like:

```
customer(bank name, bank add, branch number, brunch add, customer info...)
```

From this constructor, bank's information goes to the `Bank` class via both `Customer` and `Branch` constructors using `super()` and so on.

The problem is when I created the `Loan`, class extending the `Customer` class, then I didn't use any constructor, and I don't want to use it too, because I want only one variable from the `Customer` class. But my compiler showing this error, it is saying to use a constructor for taking all the parameters for `Bank`, `Branch`, and `Customer`'s constructors.

How can I solve this problem without using any constructor in the `Loan` class?

Comment: loan extends customer, you mean loan is customer??

Comment: When deciding to extend a class, use the "is a" test. A Branch "is a" Bank, so it might make sense to extend Bank with Branch. But Loan "is a" customer doesn't make sense. A Customer "has a" loan. Similiarly, a Customer is not a Branch. Use references instead of inheritance: Branch has Customers, Customer Has Loans

Comment: So what do u suggest to do....

Comment: You can a list of Customers in a Branch.

Comment: @user1431631 See the answers posted by myself and Frank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to avoid using the `Customer` constructor in the `Loan` class is to **not** extend `Customer`. When deciding what class to extend, if any, you should use the "is a" test. For example, a `Branch` is a `Bank`, so it makes sense to have `class Branch extends Bank`. However, `Loan` is a `Customer` doesn't really make sense, so you shouldn't do `class Loan extends Customer`. On the other hand, a `Customer` has a `Loan`; in fact, a `Customer` may have more than one `Loan` or none at all. This means that it makes sense to have a `Loan` member variable (or perhaps a `List` of `Loan`s, if you have learned about the Container API) in the `Customer` class.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to revise your OO thinking:

Branch extends Bank, Ok i can live with it, but possible not a good idea (Maybe a decorator pattern is a better way to go)

Customer extends Branch, this is not correct (try to think real live...) a Branch will have a collection of customer and possible a Customer has a field Branch, depending on your needs.

Loan extends Customer, this is not correct, a like above a Customer can have a collection of Loans and possible a Loan has a collection of Customers, depending on your needs.

So I advise you to review your object model.

Please note that having 2 way references is only a good idea if you really need it, but as i don't know your requirements i can't decide that for you.

Some articles to read:

[Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

[Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: what if i create a class instead of customers?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inheritance, use references for these classes:

```
class Bank {
    private List<Loan> loans;
}

class Loan {
    private Customer customer;
}
```

You can model this different ways: A Bank has a list of Customers, and a List of Loans, A Loan has a Customer or a Customer has a list of Loans, etc. But the important point is that one class should only extend another when it "is" that type: a Dog may extend Animal, but a Dog would not extend Kennel or Food.

When you do this you can create a Bank, passing its attributes to it in the constructor. Then create a Customer, passing only the Customer attributes to its constructor. To associate the customer to the bank, add this method to Bank:

```
public void addLoan(Loan loan) {
    this.loans.add(loan);
}
```

Then each class's constructor only needs its own attributes.